# Creating Windows Shortcuts in Linux

Tags: bash, windows, samba

Is it possible to create a Windows shortcut file (.lnk) in Bash?

No, I'm not talking about symlinks...

I need to place some Windows shortcuts in my Samba share.

Comment: I found a couple of interesting links: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776891%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Shellink_Link_Files and https://ithreats.files.wordpress.com/2009/05/lnk_the_windows_shortcut_file_format.pdf . Good luck.

Comment: IIRC Cygwin includes a utility that creates Windows shortcuts without using using Windows libraries, so it should work on Linux. I don't remember what the utility is called.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Below is a link to a Linux tool which allows you to create Windows shortcuts. The source code is available in both Bash and C:

http://www.mamachine.org/mslink/index.en.html

```
# Combine with WINE to target a path in a WINE installation
mslink.sh -l "$(winepath -w /linux/path/to/target )" -o /path/to/link.lnk
```

Comment: Confirmed that mslink can create a shortcut to a UNC path and directory; which is more than I can say for all the Python stuff I was looking at.

Comment: The author created this tool [is a SX user](https://serverfault.com/a/553974/50236), mamachine.

Comment: @Lugaxx: Would you mind if you or I edited this answer to post some usage examples for the bash script?