# Extract icons from Windows executable

Tags: windows, icons

Windows executable files ([`New`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Executable) or [`Portable` executables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable)) can contain icons. How can I extract them, either as [ICO files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)) or separate images?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are a number of tools you can use.

[`icoutils`](https://www.nongnu.org/icoutils/), available as the eponymous package in many distributions, includes a tool capable of extracting resources from most Windows executables (16-bit NE, 32-bit PE, and 64-bit PE+), `wrestool`.

```
wrestool -x --output=. -t14 /path/to/windows.exe
```

will extract the icons present in the given Windows executable and write them to individual files, named after the executable name, with the type and icon name added.

`7z` can also extract all the resources in a Windows executable;

```
7z x /path/to/windows.exe .rsrc/ICON
```

will extract all the icons in the given Windows executable and write them to individual files in the `.rsrc/ICON` directory.

Comment: I can also recommend that `wrestool` command as being capable of extracting icons from 16-bit NE-format binaries now that so many Windows utilities lost support when the Windows APIs did.

Comment: `wrestool` works fine, but `7z x` just prints info and ends with "No files to process" and "Everything is Ok". If I use option -oOUTPUT_DIR instead of directly entering the output dir at the end, it tells me it detects 62 files indeed but only generates two binaries I cannot use (CPADinfo and prot).

Answer (score 1):

To extract an icon from an executable file directly, if you have a Windows link pointing to that executable, you can use [Wine's `winemenubuilder` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/509955/13308):

```
wine winemenubuilder -t /path/to/link.lnk /path/to/image-out.png
```

I believe the command will extract the image that the link would use, whether explicitly in the link or implicitly in its target.

If you need to generate a Windows link, you can use [the `mslink` tool](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/234966/13308).

Answer (score 1):

Using icoutils package available on most distros, you can use:

```
wrestool -xt14 -o. app.exe
```

It will extract all icons into current folder, you can change folder by changing -o. to -o /path/to/extract

Then use icotool to convert images inside an ico file to png image files:

```
icotool -x filename.ico
```

You can use wildcards to iterate all icons in a folder like this:

```
icotool -x *.ico
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your distro, I like to use [icoextract](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/icoextract) under Debian.
Simple install via shell:

```
apt-get install icoextract
```

and run like:

```
icoextract /path/to/file.exe /path/to/file.ico
```

Find your new Icon file under

> /path/to/file.ico

Answer (score 0):

You can view and extract the entire contents of a DLL file on Linux using the ["Resource Hacker" snap](https://snapcraft.io/resourcehacker).

If you have Snap installed on your system, you can install it using the following command.

```bsh
sudo snap install resourcehacker
```

[image]

Note: this is a Freeware Windows app running on Linux using Wine. Wine is contained in a snap container so it won't pollute your system.